# esp-idf xTaskCreate a stack overflow in task BlinkAl-33-3

Tags: stack, overflow, esp32, freertos, esp-idf

I'm getting a strange overflow error on Esp32 that is running correctly for some time. I'm using esp-idf-v4.4

Main function is creating a task in which I'm creating another by calling

```
xTaskCreate(blinkingAlarm,(const char *) &taskName,1024,NULL,5,&taskHandle);
```

At the moment the blinkingAlarm function is almost empty and look like:

```
void blinkingAlarm(void *data) {
    uint8_t ON = 0;
    do {
        ON = !ON;
        vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    } while (1);

    vTaskDelete(NULL);
}
```

when I don't need the blinkingAlarm I'm deleting it by calling:

```
vTaskDelete(taskHandle);
```

and this is working for some time.

Each time when I call the xTaskCreate I'm making a new taskName like BlinkAl-n where n is the number of xTaskCreate that was called.

Every time after few seconds of running task from third iteration overflow error is appearing.

`***ERROR*** A stack overflow in task BlinkAl-3 has been detected.`

For test I'm using the code:

```
printf( "Task Name\tStatus\tPrio\tHWM\tTask\tAffinity\n");
char stats_buffer[1024];
vTaskList(stats_buffer);
printf("%s\n", stats_buffer);
```

to check the task name and HMW and I can see that new BlinkAl-n is created it is going each time to 3 iterations and then suddenly overflow error is appearing.

I have no idea how to deal with it. Any suggestions?

Comment: shouldn't it be `vTaskDelete(taskHandle);` Assuming you created taskhandle like this: `TaskHandle_t xHandle = NULL;`

Comment: @brushtakopo yes, actually I should write as you mention, mistype during adding the question.

Comment: Have tried to increase the `StackDepth` in the task creation? E.g. sth. like `2048` instead of `1024`?

Comment: Could you post how you create and disable the task?

Comment: @sebo1234 yes, even to 4096 and same effect